# Checking Collisions for each sprite in a group -> Attribute Error

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I would like to check to see which object(s) in a sprite group is colliding with another object and then create a new sprite at that position (like an explosion).

In a while loop, I move the objects and then check for collision.

```
if not game_over:
    move_coins()
    move_pointer()
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(pointer, coin_group):
        print_text(pygame.font.Font(None,16), 0, 0, "Collision!")
        check_collision()
```

The collision here is successful since it prints the text onto the screen.  It then continues to check_collision().

```
def check_collision():
    for coin in coin_group:
        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(coin, pointer):
            create_newcoin()

def create_newcoin():
    bcoin = Coin()
    bcoin.load("coin1s.png", 32, 32, 1)
    bcoin.position = 0,0 
    collected_group.add(bcoin)
```

The create_newcoin() function works properly outside of check_collision(), but when it runs through this loop, I get an attribute error.

```
Coin() has no attribute 'image'
```

Could anyone explain why I'm getting this error and what I need to do to fix it?  I can provide more code if necessary, but I think I have it narrowed down to this part here causing the error.  Thanks.

---

Eh, I'll just pastebin the code I'm working with.
http://pastebin.com/TuAZxUkq and http://pastebin.com/kmYytiYV

And the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Coins!\Coins!.py", line 129, in <module>
        collected_group.draw(screen)
    File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 475, in draw
        self.spritedict[spr] = surface_blit(spr.image, spr.rect)
AttributeError: 'Coin' object has no attribute 'image'
```

Comment: It looks like `Coin()` doesn't subclass `pygame.sprite.Sprite`

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but create_newcoin() can make the coin without any problems if it isn't called from check_collision().  That's why I'm confused.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing `Coin`'s definition

Comment: Can you include the full traceback? It's hard to know where the exception is coming from.

Comment: from what i can see, you have a master_image, instead of an image.
Don't know why it works outside the loop though.

Comment: I'll just paste the code, should make things clearer (hopefully).

Answer (score 0):

[`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) and [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update) are methods which are provided by `pygame.sprite.Group`.

The former delegates the to the `update` mehtod of the contained [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) - you have to implement the method. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update):

> Calls the `update()` method on all Sprites in the Group [...]

The later uses the `image` and `rect` attributes of the contained `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s to draw the objects - you have to ensure that the `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s have the required attributes. See [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw):

> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the `Sprite.image` attribute for the source surface, and `Sprite.rect`. [...]

The class `Coin` subcalss `MySprite`. `MySprite` ahs an attribute `master_image`, but no attribute `image`. Hence, calling `pygame.sprite.Group.draw()` will cause the error:

> Coin() has no attribute 'image'

Just rename `mater_image` to `image` to solve the issue:

```py
class MySprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def load(self, filename, width=0, height=0, columns=1):
        self.set_image(image e, width, height, columns)
 
    def set_image(self, image, width=0, height=0, columns=1):
        self.image = image
        # [...]
```